# How to get row referenced object from within TableCell in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I would like to have custom [`TableCell<S,T>`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html) class, which behaves depending on row object. By "row object" I mean object of type `S`, not `T`.

Apparently, [`Cell#getItem()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#getItem--) is not what I need, since it return `T`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cell.getTableView().getItems().get(cell.getIndex())
```

or

```
(S) cell.getTableRow().getItem()
```

The second one needs a cast because, for some inexplicable reason, `getTableRow()` returns a raw `TableRow`, not a `TableRow<S>`.

You may need null checks in the chain of method calls, depending on where you are doing this.